# java.lang.illegalargumentexception argument cannot be null swt

Tags: java, swt

I'm struggling with this, Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance

```
  public void gui_OCM()
  {  
    Display d = new Display();
    Shell s = new Shell(d, SWT.CLOSE);

    s.setSize(550, 390);
    s.setText("My Application");
    s.setBackground(s.getDisplay().getSystemColor(10));

    InputStream is= getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource/Hello.PNG")
    Image my_image= new Image(d,is);
```

It always shows the below Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageDataLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ocm.OCM_GUI.gui_OCM(OCM_GUI.java:69)
    at ocm.OCM_GUI.main(OCM_GUI.java:405)
```

P.S: resource is the folder in which I have placed the image
Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you print the output of System.getProperty("user.dir") before the call to getResourceAsStream so you can validate the working directory of your Java process?

Comment: It prints the location of my projects workspace.

Comment: The InputStream `is` is `null`. Make sure that the `resource` folder is on your class path. Alternatively you can put the Hellp.PNG alongside the `OCM_GUI` class and use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("resource/Hello.PNG")` to open the resource stream.

Comment: @user3087291 and is the resource folder directly under your project's workspace? This may end up being a typo for example or some limitation on the length of the path leading up to the Hello.PNG file, I suggest you post the actual output and the contents of your project folder.

Comment: Thank you all. I just put all the images in the src folder and directly gave the path as the name of the image and it worked. I know thats not the feasible solution but to make it work, I had to do that.

Comment: @user3087291 When you add a resource folder, you have to make sure it is a source folder, and not a regular folder. This might solve it.